# " 'devices' properties is not allowed" while creating docker-compose with nvidia gpu

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gpu, nvidia, nvidia-docker

### Description of the issue

### Context information (for bug reports)

**Output of `docker-compose version`**

```
docker-compose version 1.17.1, build unknown
docker-py version: 2.5.1
CPython version: 2.7.17
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

**Output of `docker version`**

```
Client:
 Version:           19.03.6
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        369ce74a3c
 Built:             Fri Dec 18 12:21:44 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.6
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       369ce74a3c
  Built:            Thu Dec 10 13:23:49 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.3.3-0ubuntu1~18.04.4
  GitCommit:        
 runc:
  Version:          spec: 1.0.1-dev
  GitCommit:        
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:
```

**Output of `docker-compose config`**
(Make sure to add the relevant `-f` and other flags)

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.testserver.deploy.resources.reservations value Additional properties are not allowed ('devices' was unexpected)
```

### Steps to reproduce the issue

1. Creating a Dockerfile with a simple pull of nvidia cuda image and a command to check the nvidia-gpu

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-base
CMD nvidia-smi
```

2.Works like a charm when we build the image and run it without docker compose

```
docker image build testserver/ -t testserverimage
docker run --gpus all -exec -it testserverimage
```

Shows the nvidia-gpu devices

```
Sat Feb 20 13:10:46 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           Off  | 00001918:00:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   52C    P0    71W / 149W |   7897MiB / 11441MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

3. Now creating the docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  testserver:
    image: nvidia/cuda:10.2-base
    build: './modelserver'
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - capabilities: [gpu]
              driver: nvidia
```

#### Observed result

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.testserver.deploy.resources.reservations value Additional properties are not allowed ('devices' was unexpected)
```

#### Expected result

```
Sat Feb 20 13:10:46 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           Off  | 00001918:00:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   52C    P0    71W / 149W |   7897MiB / 11441MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

#### Stacktrace / full error message

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.testserver.deploy.resources.reservations value Additional properties are not allowed ('devices' was unexpected)
```

### Additional information

OS version / distribution, `docker-compose` install method, etc.
OS Information:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Docker compose installation:

```
sudo apt  install docker-compose
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the documentation https://docs.docker.com/compose/gpu-support/#enabling-gpu-access-to-service-containers :

> Docker Compose **v1.28.0+** allows to define GPU reservations using the device structure defined in the Compose Specification.

Your docker-compose version is 1.17.1, so you need to upgrade your docker-compose to, at least, 1.28.0.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really did miss the versioning because I thought that installing from "apt" would always give me the latest version. Not going to happen from next time Thank you again.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is too old to have docker-compose 1.28 in it's repository.

Comment: Yes, @zigarn. Again, Thank you for your help.